# Some perfect combination Foundation (by Zurb) and js framework?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, zurb-foundation, canjs

There's a lot of MVC frameworks like Backbone, AngularJS, CanJS and more... Which framework fits perfectly to Foundation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation is a Front-End responsive framework. It was mainly built to help designers create web applications that will adapt to any device screen. So, it is not an MVC (or [MV*](http://merrickchristensen.com/articles/learn-js/mvstar-libraries-and-frameworks.html)) framework. You can use ANY of the frameworks you mentioned with Foundation seamlessly.

You should just try to focus on which of the mentioned frameworks fits best to the kind of application you want to design. Each of them has different strengths and weaknesses. Here are some links that may help you out:

- [Top Ten JavaScript Front-End Frameworks](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/)
- [Client-Side MVC frameworks compared](http://paulhammant.com/2012/02/13/client-side-mvc-frameworks-compared/)
- [Journey Through The JavaScript MVC Jungle](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/)

After you decide on one, adding Foundation is very simple.